# How to align images in a row in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, text-align

Hey i am aligning 5 images in a row having col-md-2 spacing. But i want to align the row in the middle of the page. Can anyone help how can i acheve this row?

I have just tried the offset col. But it is not working properly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
            <img src="images/symbol1.png" alt="step 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="images/symbol2.png" alt="step 1">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="images/symbol3.png" alt="step 1">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="images/symbol4.png" alt="step 1">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="images/symbol5.png" alt="step 1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that `the offset col is not working properly`?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for?

```
   <div class="container" style="width: 50%">
        <div class="row" align="center">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                <img src="images/symbol1.png" alt="step 1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/symbol2.png" alt="step 1">
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/symbol3.png" alt="step 1">
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/symbol4.png" alt="step 1">
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/symbol5.png" alt="step 1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's [alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment). Just add the `.text-center` class to the row.

Please check the result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
            <img src="//placehold.it/100x100/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="step 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/100x100/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="step 1">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/100x100/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="step 1">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/100x100/c69/f9c/?text=4" alt="step 1">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/100x100/9c6/cf9/?text=5" alt="step 1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```